# Need to append data to existing xml file in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm writing data to an xml file on the sdcard. I want append data right before the root node closes in xml. Could someone help me figure out how to do that?

I'm using [RandomAccessFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to write data in the xml doc, but it seems to be appending data right after the root node opens and I want to insert data before the root node closes. I thought `(my_file_path.length()) -1)` would take the pointer before the root node closes but does not.

I would really appreciate your input on this. Thank you.

```
if(xml_file.exists()) {
  StringWriter writer2;

  String my_file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/App" + "/AppData.xml";
  RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(my_file_path, "rw");
  raf.seek((my_file_path.length()) -1);

  XmlSerializer xmlSerializer5 = Xml.newSerializer();
  writer2 = new StringWriter();
  xmlSerializer5.setOutput(writer2);
  xmlSerializer5.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
  xmlSerializer5.startTag(null, "data");

  xmlSerializer5.startTag(null, "name");
  xmlSerializer5.text("Lisa Doe");
  xmlSerializer5.endTag(null, "name");
  xmlSerializer5.endTag(null, "data");
  xmlSerializer5.flush();

  String my_dataWrite = writer2.toString();
  raf.write(my_dataWrite.getBytes());
  raf.close();

}
```

I would like my xml file to look like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<root>
  <data>
    <name>John Doe</name>
  </data>
  <data>
    <name>Lisa Doe</name>
  </data>
</root>
```

but instead it's appending data to the beginning of file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<root>
  <data>
    <name>Lisa Doe</name>
  </data>
  <data>
    <name>John Doe</name>
  </data>
</root>
```